# Correctly parsing data with jq

Tags: python, stream, jq

I have the following data:

```
[
    {
        "M": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "nk": "MATH$$SPRING$$INST1$$2",
                "section": {
                    "nk": "MATH$$SPRING$$INST1",
                    "course": 1,
                    "id": 1
                },
                "location": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "nk": "mcu$$101",
                    "campus": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "nk": "mcu",
                        "name": "Main Campus"
                    },
                    "address": "1 st",
                    "building": "1",
                    "room": "101"
                },
                "day_of_week": 2,
                "start_time": "09:00:00",
                "end_time": "10:00:00"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "nk": "ENG$$SPRING$$INST2$$2",
                "section": {
                    "nk": "ENG$$SPRING$$INST2",
                    "course": 2,
                    "id": 4
                },
                "location": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "nk": "mcu$$201",
                    "campus": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "nk": "mcu",
                        "name": "Main Campus"
                    },
                    "address": "1 st",
                    "building": "1",
                    "room": "201"
                },
                "day_of_week": 2,
                "start_time": "09:00:00",
                "end_time": "10:00:00"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "nk": "ENG$$SPRING$$INST2$$22",
                "section": {
                    "nk": "ENG$$SPRING$$INST2",
                    "course": 2,
                    "id": 4
                },
                "location": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "nk": "mcu$$201",
                    "campus": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "nk": "mcu",
                        "name": "Main Campus"
                    },
                    "address": "1 st",
                    "building": "1",
                    "room": "201"
                },
                "day_of_week": 2,
                "start_time": "10:00:00",
                "end_time": "11:00:00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "W": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "nk": "MATH$$SPRING$$INST1$$4",
                "section": {
                    "nk": "MATH$$SPRING$$INST2",
                    "course": 1,
                    "id": 2
                },
                "location": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "nk": "mcu$$201",
                    "campus": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "nk": "mcu",
                        "name": "Main Campus"
                    },
                    "address": "1 st",
                    "building": "1",
                    "room": "201"
                },
                "day_of_week": 4,
                "start_time": "08:00:00",
                "end_time": "10:00:00"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm trying to extract "W"'s list.

When i do: `jq('[.[].W][]').transform(data)` i get None, But when i do `jq('[.[].M][]').transform(data)` I get the desired result. Why im i experiencing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to extract "W"'s list.

OK, so let's first deal with jq, and then with the python interface.

### jq

`.[]` yields all the items in the top-level array, and therefore
`.[] | .W` will yield two items:

- `null` (because the first item does not have .W), and
- the desired list

To extract just "W"'s list, you could use any of the following filters,
depending on your precise requirements:

```
.[] | select(has("W")) | .W

.[] | .W | select(.)

.[] | .W // empty

.[1].W
```

## from jq import jq

As the documentation at https://pypi.org/project/pyjq/ says:

> If multiple_output is False (the default), then the first output is used

For example:

```
print jq('1,2').transform(data)
```

yields just `1`.

### In summary

Depending on the precise requirements, you can use any of the filters given above, for example:

```
jq('.[] | .W // empty').transform(data)
```

### Moral

If there's a moral to this tale, it might be that, when in doubt, one should consider using jq (the command-line executable) or jqplay to make sure your jq filter is doing what you want.

Comment: That makes SOO much sense, i wish i could upvote you twice! Thanks!